# How to match more than one instance of a single subexpression?

Tags: regular-expressions, major-mode, font-lock

I'm trying to use a regular expression of the form `"foo\\(?:\\(bar\\)\\(baz\\)\\)*\\(quux\\)"`, but I want the inner two subexpressions to retain *all* of their matches, not just the first one.  I realize this may be impossible to achieve as stated, so I'll give more detail about why I want this to work.

My specific case is that I'm trying produce a major mode for editing and highlighting [Dwarf Fortress "raw" files](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Raw_file).  The regular expression I'm having this trouble with is

```
"\\(\\[\\)\\([_A-Z]+\\)\\(?:\\(:\\)\\([^][:]*\\)\\)*\\(\\]\\)"
```

, which successfully matches a single complete raw tag with all of its parameters; however, capturing groups 3 and 4 only end up containing the last parameter (after having successfully matched all the previous ones), and therefore all but the last parameter is not highlighted by `font-lock`.  I understand *why* this is the case, but I'd like to know if there is a way to get around it, or to otherwise enable my desired behavior.

Comment: Is `"foo\\(?:bar\\|baz\\)*\\(quux\\)"` what you want? Note the or-operator `\\|`.

Comment: @Tobias No; I need it to match things of the pattern `foo bar baz bar baz … bar baz quux` and highlight all the `bar baz` pairs in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an **anchored** font-lock rule. They are used when you want a search within a search. The look like:

```
(PATTERN
 (SUBPATTERN
  PRE-MATCH-FORM
  POST-MATCH-FORM
  HIGHLIGHT
  ...))
```

In your case, it could be something like:

```
(defvar my-raw-rule
  '(("\\["
     ("\\_<\\(\\sw\\|\\s_\\)+\\_>"
      ;; Pre-match form: Limit search to closing "]" or end-of-line.
      (save-excursion
        (if (re-search-forward "\\]" (line-end-position) t)
            (point)
          nil))
      ;; Post-match form
      nil
      (0 font-lock-constant-face)))))
```

Note that the rule highlights words after the `[` even when the `]` isn't present -- this is typically what you want when writing code.